# Fabric.js javascript framework for rich text editing

Tags: jquery, html, canvas, fabricjs

We are using fabric.js java script framework as it has nice api's for canvas drawing . but we need to support rich text editing feature using this framework, ,for example if i have a textbox i want to type in the textbox, and want to do text partial editing like change its colour font etc and save it on canvas.

One option I have is to first create a normal textbox do a partial editing in it and the generated html i have to convert it into canvas text by fill text etc.

What should be the best approach for this ?

Comment: I wrote a [this blog article about one possibility](http://abdiassoftware.com/blog/2013/10/using-svg-to-automatically-format-and-wrap-text-on-a-canvas-element/) but it isn't for fabric as you would need to use other mechanisms. But you could probably use it in *combination* with fabric and other libraries that support drawing images to canvas.

Comment: Thanks Ken, i guess it is the same as mentioned in below link of MDN:- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/HTML/Canvas/Drawing_DOM_objects_into_a_canvas , but this is not working in IE9, does you example support IE9 as well ?

Comment: yes, it's in part based on that (I provide a link at the bottom to it). I am not sure about IE9 as I don't have access to one but initially I would be skeptic.. The only other option for canvas is to make a parser to replicate the formatting (html2canvas and the other libraries can probably give some code input for this - or perhaps you can just use the library to do all for you. You could isolate the textarea in an iframe so html2canvas only grabs that portion).

Comment: btw: If you go to my article with IE9 you can see if the live demos there works.. if the text shows up in the canvas it means it will work with ie9.

Comment: I checked and in IE9, the error is coming "Line: 44 Error: 'Blob' is undefined" , When I checked on net i found Blob is not supported in IE9, it is supported in IE10 instead..

Comment: btw: how it can be achieved using Iframe, you mentioned in previous comment, could you please elaborate more.. thanks.

Comment: @ammu don't forget to accept an answer if it answers your question ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You mean like this?

[image]

or like this?

[image]

I'm working on it at the moment :) The native support is coming to Fabric in couple weeks.

Comment: Will be there very soon!

Comment: We need both & its a good news, We all are waiting for this one .. Please update here once completed ..

Comment: i also want this feature in fabric.

Comment: This is now mostly done. See tests — fabricjs.com/test/misc/itext.html and ticket tracking features — https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/issues/945 Testing is always welcome!

Comment: @kangax how can I use this feature? I am using 1.3.0 dev build what should I add more?

Comment: @Thirumalaimurugan this feature will be available in upcoming 1.4.0 (or you can try it now; it's in the source on github)

Comment: Yes I saw its cool, thank you, one more question if i want to use this fabric.js in mobile developement can i use, becuase i can see some performance issue when i m testing in android 4.3 version..

Comment: @Thirumalaimurugan performance issues with iText? We're working on optimizations right now. 1.4.4 should be much better.

Comment: one more question, 1) while editing in text if font family is H2HDRM and browser is IE9 & IE10 , then user enter consecutive space key in Text box then it shows space as empty square boxes 2) while editing in text if font family is H2HDRM and browser is IE-10 , if tilde key with out using shift key (above to tab key) is pressed , it is displayed as space